# Get the response Content-Type header from XHR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-type, xmlhttprequest

I would like to see whether the header was text/html or text/xml. If it was text/html then there was an error and I would rather catch that before proceeding.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the [getResponseHeader()](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getresponseheader()-method) method.

Minimal example:

```
<script>
function hand () {
        console.log(this.getResponseHeader('content-type'));
}
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onreadystatechange = hand;
x.open('GET', 'index.html', true);
x.send();
</script>
```

Comment: Why did you call it `hand`?

Comment: Because I was too lazy to type out `handler` in full.

Comment: Would that work even with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` when some headers are sent after the message body?

Comment: @Ωmega I think it depends on the XHR's readyState (`LOADING` as opposed to `DONE`).

Comment: Thanks, this will come in handy