# Integrate epub.js into firefox as default reader of .epub

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, epub

On my PC I use the Firefox AddOn [Lucifox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lucifox/) to read EPUB books.
It is good but it takes over the *RightClick* context menu.
So I can't easily search/translate a phrase I highlight on the page.
The less light-weight AddOn [EPUBReader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/epubreader/) is the same.
That defect is avoided by the pure javscript EPUB reader called [epub.js](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js).
It can be embedded into a webpage using the following javascript:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/epub.js/0.2.11/epub.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var book = ePub("url/to/book/");
  book.renderTo("area");
</script>
<div id="area"></div>
```

Code from [here](http://futurepress.org/).

**My question**: is there away - say with Greasemonkey or similar - in Firefox to automatically embed opened epubs using this system? So I don't have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject scripts from Greasemonkey by

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = ' /* your script */ ';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

JS libraries can be locally stored once together with the userscript and reused on every site load by the meta block entry `@require`

Since addons are nothing more than zipped JavaScript projects, you could also unzip the .xpi file (rename extension it if needed), modify the code and repack it using zip. The file should be renamed to .xpi after all. You can even develop it as unpacked addon.

Comment: but how could I trigger such a script injection - based on mime/file type epub?

Comment: That's up to you. You could e.g. add a `keydown` event listener or insert a button into the DOM. Aaahm... you might mean something like a `@match` meta block?

Comment: How is the epub loaded? An Idea could be to intercept the link and give the URL to the library script. Isn't the file extension enough? Or based on AJAX request see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907876/get-the-response-content-type-header-from-xhr . To intercept AJAX requests, you have to manipulate the XMLHttpRequest.prototype.

Comment: Or better proxify the XMLHttpRequest object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy . Again: Think about modifying the addon. That could be the way of lowest resistance.